# Command not found unix shell scripting

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement, command, sh

So I'm currently working on a school project and I'm trying to write a shell script that will eventually decide which class gradle will build on.  But I keep getting an error each time I choose either 1 or 2, but if I select anything else, the script prompts me the correct results.

Example 1:
If input = 1

```
Do you wish to play Tic Tac Toe as a web app or simply in the terminal? (1)Web app (2)Terminal
1
./testScript.sh: line 6: [ 1: command not found
1
```

Example 2: If input != 1 or 2

```
Do you wish to play Tic Tac Toe as a web app or simply in the terminal? (1)Web app (2)Terminal
5
You have insulted us, go home!
```

-

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Do you wish to play Tic Tac Toe as a web app or simply in the terminal? (1)Web app (2)Terminal"
read input

if [ "$input" != "1" ] || [ "$input" != "2" ]; then
    echo "You have insulted us, go home!"
elif [ "$input" = "1" ]; then
    echo "1"
elif [ "$input" = "2" ]; then
    echo "2"
fi
```

I've read and googled but the only suggestion I find is that I need to add spaces between if and [, and between [ and ". But as you can see that is not the case.

Comment: your code runs here on bash/ BTW you mean `if [ "$input" != "1" ] && [ "$input" != "2" ]`. Can you type `echo $SHELL` and post the results?

Comment: Are you sure you have a real ASCII space, not a non-breaking space, between these characters? If you copied-and-pasted from a web source, you could easily have gotten a different type of character.

Comment: BTW, a `case` statement is going to be a much easier way to write this code. `case $input in 1) echo "1";; 2) echo "2";; *) echo "You have insulted us, go home!";; esac`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I would have directly answered that, but the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, indeed -- hence my guess of a non-breaking space rather than an ASCII space.

Comment: echo $SHELL prompts /bin/bash.  And I'm pretty sure that these are not non-breaking spaces as I wrote this all in vim.

Comment: @hjaltist, what does `bash -x yourscript` log?

Comment: @hjaltist so the best way now is to copy/paste from SO question back to the OP's code and it will work :) (fix the && issue first)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, heh, yup -- indeed, either `[ "$input" != 1 ]` or `[ "$input" != 2 ]` will *always* be true.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre haha wow I didn't see that, but I've changed it from || to && and the error is gone if I choose 1 but it's still there if input is 2

Comment: and if I choose anything else I don't get prompted with the "You have ins..." statement

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, is there another editor I should be using to avoid this problem in the future?